# Apache Crunch Error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I have command that reads the *.avro file and loads into the table 
loadavro *.avro tablename

when I  try to run the code in vagrant cluster and it's throwing following error

```
[root@cdh4-cluster vagrant]# hadoop jar devcenter-store-load-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar loadavro person.avro person_table



Unexpected exception: Cannot create job output directory /tmp/crunch-1880716375
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create job output directory /tmp/crunch-1880716375
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.dist.DistributedPipeline.createTempDirectory(DistributedPipeline.java:281)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.dist.DistributedPipeline.<init>(DistributedPipeline.java:88)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.MRPipeline.<init>(MRPipeline.java:88)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.MRPipeline.<init>(MRPipeline.java:76)
        at com.cerner.devcenter.pipeline.crunch.PersonRecordPipeline.getPipelineInstance(PersonRecordPipeline.java:72)
        at com.cerner.devcenter.pipeline.crunch.PersonRecordPipeline.writeIntoHBase(PersonRecordPipeline.java:53)
        at com.cerner.console.commands.LoadAvroCommand.run(LoadAvroCommand.java:35)
        at com.cerner.kepler.commands.Command.run(Command.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at com.cerner.kepler.commands.BasicCommandRunner.run(BasicCommandRunner.java:61)
        at com.cerner.kepler.commands.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:19)
        at com.cerner.console.main.ConsoleMain.main(ConsoleMain.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/crunch-1880716375. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 104 needs additional 2 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 106. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:2960)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2938)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44096)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1695)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1691)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
        at $Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:425)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
        at $Proxy11.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2092)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1902)
        at org.apache.crunch.impl.dist.DistributedPipeline.createTempDirectory(DistributedPipeline.java:279)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the exception you can see that the NameNode is in safe mode so the crunch job can't write any new files into HDFS. Take the NameNode out the safe mode and run the job again. hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave